# How to use property binding for [autofocus] attribute (property) of <input> tag in HTML file to a boolean variable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I am new to Angular,
I want to set focus on an input tag on the basis of a value of a boo-lean variable. i.e if the value of variable is 'true', the focus is set on input tag and if it is false then not.

I have shared my code below:

app.component.html

```
<select #clickedValue (change)="onValueChange(clickedValue.value)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input [autofocus]="change" [disabled]="change" type="text">
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'focusChange';
  change = false;
  renderer = Renderer2;
  onValueChange(value)
  {
    console.log(this.change);
    console.log("value changed",value);
    this.change = true;
    console.log(this.change);
  }

}
```

I have also attached the screen shots:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

So, what I want is whenever I select/change value from drop-down, the focus should automatically shift to next input box.

It is working properly for [disabled] attribute but not for [autofocus] attribute.

Please help me to find out how can I do this or what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Try using ViewChild for the input you want to focus on. And manually focus the element in onValueChange method

Comment: When you change the value of select your disabled becomes true [disabled]="change" , If disabled is true, the focus won't work. You should make it as [disabled]="!change"

Comment: @VinodBhavnani i tried doing that and also i tried with removing the disabled attribute but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `@ViewChild('yourInput') searchBox;` and add `#yourInput` reference variable in `<input #yourInput [disabled]="change" type="text">`

Then you can make it focus by using

`setTimeout(() => this.yourInput.nativeElement.focus(), 0);` as part of your logic.

Comment: thanks for your input, it worked!. But my concern is why property binding is not working with [autofocus] attribute, when it  is not giving any error on console also

Comment: I think it has something to do with angular's lifecycles. My understanding is it's more "Angular" to use ViewChild than [autofocus].